# how to get a commented script using xpath?

Tags: javascript, html, xpath

i tried this to get the commented script

```
 //script/comment()
```

turn out it dosent work for comment in script

the script is like this :

```
<script type='text/javascript'>
 <!--
 script I want to get
 //-->\n </script>
```

how can i get the "

> script i want to get

"?
if i replace comment() with  text()  i'm only getting \n as a result.
that mean it's not considering the comment block
thanks for your help.

Comment: Try providing a [mcve]. How are you running the XPath? How are you getting the HTML into the XPath engine?

Comment: If you are writing HTML then `<!-- ... -->` is not a comment since script elements contain CDATA.

Comment: Can you edit the HTML? There's no reason to wrap scripts in `<!-- //-->` now that people don't use Netscape 2.